# Is the "true" result of >, <, !, &&, || or == defined?

Tags: c, logical-operators

When I for instance write `7>1` in C (say C99 if this is not an always-been feature), can I expect the result will be exactly 1 or just some non-zero value?  Does this hold for all bool operators?

Comment: It is most likely a duplicate, but I was not able to find it :-(

Comment: @TRD: Incorrect.  The C expression `7>1` yields a result of type `int` with the value `1`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In C99 §6.5.8 Relational Operators, item 6 (`<`,`>`,`<=` and `>=`):

> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >=
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield **1** if the specified relation is true and **0** if it is false)
>   The result has type **int**.

As for equality operators, it's a bit further in §6.5.9 (`==` and `!=`):

> The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational
>   operators except for their lower precedence) Each of the operators yields **1** if the
>   specified relation is true and **0** if it is false. The result has type **int**. For any pair of
>   operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

The logical AND and logical OR are yet a bit further in §6.5.13 (`&&`)

> The && operator shall yield **1** if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields **0**. The result has type **int**.

... and §6.5.14 (`||`)

> The || operator shall yield **1** if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields **0**. The result has type **int**.

And the semantics of the unary arithmetic operator `!` are over at §6.5.3.3/4:

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is **0** if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to 0, **1** if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type **int**.
>   The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

Result type is `int` across the board, with `0` and `1` as possible values. (Unless I missed some.)

Comment: And conveniently stdbool.h defines true and false as 1 and 0 (C99 7.16).

Comment: Good, especially since && and || behave differently in other languages (returning the last evaluated value).  If the standard operators aren't involved, clamping can be done by using `!!` or [casting to `<stdbool.h>` `bool`](http://www.jacquesf.com/2011/04/in-defense-of-the-c99-boolean-type/).

Answer (score 15):

C follows [Postel's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel#Postel.27s_Law) for its boolean operators: be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others. It will treat any non-zero value as true in boolean expressions, but it will always produce either a 0 or a 1 itself. `2 != 3` is always `1`.

Answer (score 6):

From the ISO C99 standard, section 6.5.8:

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has
>   type int.

From section 6.5.9:

> 3 The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to
>   the relational  operators except for their lower precedence. Each
>   of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if
>   it is false. The result has type int. For any pair of  operands,
>   exactly one of the relations is true.

Same thing happens with the logical conjunction (`&&`) and disjunction (`||`) operators.

PS: Incidentally, this is why the bitwise operators (`&` and `|`) can usually be used as non-short-circuiting versions of the logical operators.

Answer (score 4):

All C *operators* that yield logically true/false values always yield a result of type `int` with the value `0` for false, `1` for true.

That's not the case for all C *expressions* that yield logically true/false values.  For example, the `is*()` character classification functions declared in `<ctype.h>` (`isdigit()`, `isupper()`, etc.) return `0` if the condition is false, but may return any non-zero value if the condition is true.

As long as you use the result directly as a condition:

```
if (isdigit(c)) ...
if (!isdigit(c)) ...
if (isdigit(c) || islower(c)) ...
```

and *don't* attempt to compare it to something:

```
if (isdigit(c) == 1) ...    /* WRONG */
if (isdigit(c) == true) ... /* ALSO WRONG */
```

this shouldn't cause any problems.

(You *can* safely compare the result to `0` or `false`, but there's no good reason to do so; that's what the `!` operator is for.)