# changing if-else statements for integer programming

Tags: if-statement, integer

How should I change these if statements to constraints for IP?

```
If x-y>=0 then z=0
if x-y<0  then z=1
```

Comment: jtheman I am looking for a solution like this http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-01.html

Comment: So it is not really language dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming C (98) like language, where [boolean expression yields 0 or 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687403/is-the-true-result-of-or-defined):

```
z = x-y<0
```

`z` will be a boolean value which is true if `x-y <0`, but the evaluation is actually `true=1`, `false=0` - and it will get you what you are after.

Comment: But I can not have such thing in integer programming constraint! Can you explain more plz?

Comment: @sweet: It does exactly what you are after, assuming boolean is evaluated to one of `{0,1}` (as the link suggests). However, yes - this behavior is language dependent. In java for example - a `boolean` is NOT an `int` with value of {0,1}.