# Type of the result of a comparison of float with int in C

Tags: c, int, comparison

The book I am using to learn C says that if a binary operator (except `=`, `&&` and `||`) is used with one operand of floating point type (say, `float`) and one operand of integer type (say, `int`) then the integer value is converted to a floating point value, **and that this floating point type will also be the type of the result of the operation**.

I don't understand the bold part. Why should, e.g., the comparison operator `<` return a float?

I tried

```
float a=2.0;
int b=1;
printf("%d\n",(b<a)*16777217);
```

and it prints 16777217 as I expected. The number 16777217 is not representable as a float on my system.

So I would think this shows that the type of `(b<a)` is int, not float - if it were float then `(b<a)*16777217` would be of type float as well, and its value would be nearby the value 16777217, and this nearby value would get printed.

More, if I try

```
float a=2.0;
int b=1;
printf("%f\n",(b<a)*16777217);
```

it prints 0.000000.

Am I getting something wrong, or is the claim in my book wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687403/is-the-true-result-of-or-defined - relational operators have a "return type" of `int`.

Comment: Yes, probably they were, in mind, referring to arithmetic operators... But it's definitely not in their text.

Comment: @SJuan76 No. In C, `<` and co do not return a boolean. See any C standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your particular question is about the type of `a < b`. In C, this expression has type `int`. The C99 standard, 6.5.8:6, says:

> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has
>   type `int`.

---

Your general question is about recognizing the type of an expression in C. There is no easy way to do this with just an ordinary C99 compiler, but I offer two solutions below. One attempt you made was `printf("%f\n",(b<a)*16777217);`. This does not work. This `printf()` call invokes undefined behavior because you are passing an integer for the `%f` format. This is not the right way to test the type of an expression in C.

Instead:

- If you have a C11 compiler, use `_Generic`, a [newly introduced construct](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html) that evaluates to different values depending on the type of an expression.
- If you have the static analysis and transformation framework for C programs [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/download.html), declare a variable of type `typeof(e)` in a program and use `frama-c -print` to see what type this was resolved to.

Here is an example program that declares a variable `X` with the same type as `(b<a)*16777217`:

```
int main(){
  float a=2.0;
  int b=1;
  typeof((b<a)*16777217) X = 0;
}
```

This program is normalized and re-printed by Frama-C with the command below:

```
$ frama-c t.c -print
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  t.c"
/* Generated by Frama-C */
int main(void)
{
  int __retres;
  float a;
  int b;
  int X; // <- THE EXPRESSION HAD TYPE int
  a = (float)2.0;
  b = 1;
  X = 0;
  __retres = 0;
  return __retres;
}
```

There were other oddities in my original program that were normalized at the same time as `typeof`: I forgot a `return` statement in function `main()` (as is legal in C99) so one was added. I was initializing the `float` variable `a` with the `double` constant `2.0` so the conversion was made explicit. The transformed, normalized program is still equivalent to the original.